# Launch4J generated exe gets "a Java exception has occurred"

Tags: java, exception, launch4j

We've recently made some structural changes to our large application.  It's been being built and launched with Launch4J for a long time.  We're using a 1.7 JVM installed in our app directory.

With our latest changes, the Launch4J generated .exe no longer works.

When we run it, it immediately pops up with a error dialog:

```
Title:Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Message: A Java Exception has occurred.
```

As far as I can tell, our app never even starts.
the Launch4J log file starts like this:

```
Version:        3.6
CmdLine:        C:\Program Files\EFI\Metrix\Metrix.exe --l4j-debug-all
WOW64:          yes
Resource 101:   An error occurred while starting the application.
Resource 8:     .
Working dir:    C:\Program Files\EFI\Metrix\.
...
```

That "Resource 101:" line is the only info I have.
How can I find out exactly what the error was?

Comment: Try running it from the `command prompt` or some other `CLI` to see the errors . Does the .jar has dependencies on other .jar libraries? Do you changed anything in the settings of Launch4J? Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally tracked this down.  Due to a bad merge, one of our .jar files got left out of the classpath, so the app was getting a classnotfoundexception during startup.

Seems like this is in the kind of error that Launch4J should report in a useful way.